# I keep getting the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java

I get the runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
at Series.series(Series.java:10)
at Series.main(Series.java:21)
```

in lines 10 and 21 and can't figure out what's wrong. I am trying to make the program sum the series 1 - 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3... n*x^(n-1). Any help I can get would be much appreciated!

```
public class Series {

public static double series (double x, int n) {

    int increase = n;
    double sign = Math.pow(-1.0, increase+1);
    double exponent = Math.pow(x, increase-1);
    double[] A = new double[n];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        A[i] = (sign) * ((increase + 1) - A.length) * (exponent); increase = increase + 1;
    }
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            sum = sum + A[i];
        }
    return sum;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    System.out.print("series(0.5, 1)  should be  1.0");
    System.out.println(" : " + series(0.5, 1));
}
}
```

Comment: Is it (1 - 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3... n*x^(n-1)?) or 
(1+ 2x + 3x^2 + 4x^3... n*x^(n-1))

Comment: Usually loop conditions should use `<`, not `<=`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem:-

`double[] A = new double[n];`

`n=1`, which means, you can access only `A[0]`.

But your `for` loop:-

`for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)` - this iterates to `i<=n`(**i becomes 1** for second iteration), which means it actively tries to access `A[1]` which throws the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

Comment: Thank you! I changed that little detail and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The last index of your array is (n-1). When i==n, the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The array index starts from zero. In the code `double[] A = new double[n]`, where n=1 implies an array of size one will be created whose index starts from zero.

(i.e.:) A[0] and since you run for loop twice `for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)`,the second time when the loop runs, it tries to locate an array with index one (i.e.:) A[1] which doesn't exist and hence `JVM` throws you the exception.

Remove the equal to sign from the for loop `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`, your code would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

Because, when you are at 1 = 1, the code tries to assign a value to a[1]. This element is not present as the array size itself is 1. So the array contains {a[0]} only.

Answer (score 0):

int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
Here,you are also visiting the i=n,which gives an arrayindexoutofbounds exception!

Answer (score 0):

The problem the first for loop:

```
double[] A = new double[n];
```

You've created array with n elements. First index in array is `0`. Lets imagine that `n` equals 5 so indexes in your array will look like `[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        A[i] = (sign) * ((increase + 1) - A.length) * (exponent); increase = increase + 1;
    }
```

In this loop your condition is `<=` so when `n == 5` you will try to insert extra `6th` element, as you already inserted element in `zero index`

Answer (score 0):

double[] A = new double[n+1];

this will solve your problem